# Creating reactJs production web app and deploy to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have react web app running locally on my machine now I want to put this on heroku.I know before publishing it globally I need to run.

```
npm run build
```

In order to generate production ready code.My question is what if after generating production code and pushing it to heroku if I change something in react code so again do I need to run npm run build command before pushing it to heroku.

Someone please clear my doubt. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need to build again. However, it would be a shorter time span the next time.

Comment: That means for every change I need to build and push it on heroku to update change globally.

Comment: Yes, that is required.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer correct if it helped :)